# Do I give out bad pieces, if my BitTorrent Client can't access a file?

Tags: bittorrent

UPDATE: My original question really boils down to this: If I set a file to not accessible (e. g. with "chmod 000 file"), would I give out bad pieces to other Peers? And why so?

ORIGINAL: I have some huge torrents, where each has 1000 files. I only need like 200 of them. Is there any possibility to skip the remaining 800 files? I can easily create a list from all the unwanted (or wanted files) from a database.

Comment: My first idea was to just create files with the exact same filename. But these files just get overwritten. I could set their permission to not accessible (e.g. chmod 000). In the uTorrent Forum their comment was that this would give out bad pieces and I would get banned for hashfails. But how can it give out bad pieces, if the files aren't accessible?

Answer (score 0):

Many torrent programs will allow you the option to not download certain files in the torrent. You will have to find it in the download options yourself. If you are unable to, then you might need to get another torrent client.

Comment: I'm aware of that e.g. uTorrent has this option. But it's not really practical to manually select 800 files per torrent, if there is not a pattern (like ordering by filesize or name). Maybe my question really is: Why would it give out bad pieces if the files aren't accessible?

Comment: Sounds more like a problem with whoever created the torrent file